# Alfresco -Migration new theme from sdk 2 to sdk 3.0.1

Tags: migration, alfresco, alfresco-share

i have succed to add a new theme with alfresco sdk 2:

[image]

i need to upgrade to sdk 3.0.1

I understand (but i may be wrong) that  src/main/amp/web directory of my sdk 2 project, moves to src/main/assembly/web directory of my project-share-jar :

[image]

But what about src/main/amp/config ???

I have updated share-jar pom file like this :

[image]

and platform-jar like this :

[image]

but i'm not sure it's right.

What is the best way to do that ?

Comment: are you wanted to move themes from sdk2 to sdk 3.0 ?

Comment: yes but i found how to do :https://community.alfresco.com/message/827447-re-migration-new-theme-from-sdk-2-to-sdk-301?commentID=827447&et=watches.email.thread#comment-827447

Comment: means , you got your answer right !

Answer (score 0):

src/main/amp/config goes to src/main/resources
src/main/amp/web can go to assembly folder or META-INF

What was your question? Are you test it and this is not working?

Comment: All is ok now : https://community.alfresco.com/message/827447-re-migration-new-theme-from-sdk-2-to-sdk-301?commentID=827447&et=watches.email.thread#comment-827447